# How to add Brainfuck into Atom

Tags: atom-editor, brainfuck

I know nothing about grammars or that type of stuff and i don't know how to make brainfuck work in
Atom. I have installed script and brainfuck, but if I try to run it just prints the error "Command not configured for Brainfuck!". can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i have found (https://atom.io/packages/language-brainfuck) hope that works.

if it doesn't so you may try downloading an interpreter manually [a link of bf interpreter is here](https://github.com/PrashanthKumar0/bf-interpreter/) .